# Attempt to attach an auto-named database when installing my app in another pc

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I recently finished building this C# Winforms app that uses a localDB connection and when installing it on another PC, I get the error as shown in the title, even though I included the SQL Server Express localDB in the prerequisites folder.

I tried all kinds of solutions like changing the method of how to build the setup file (using Advanced Installer), but it seems that the problem is always related to the constant `AttachDbFilename` attribute of the connection string that's not changing according to where the database is newly installed.

Here's how the connection string is defined in the `App.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="client" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Surface\source\repos\VisaTurbo\VisaTurbo\Client.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Please I've been stuck with this problem for 3 days now and the due date to submit the application have already been reached.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can by example check the database file exist in %userProfile%\DBName.mdf and create a new one with https://github.com/martincostello/sqllocaldb.
But this make the connectionstrings parameters obsolete :)

You can also generate a new one with [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)
But if the user move the database file this will reset the application each time.
That's why in general the database in on a server, not locally stored on the user's machine.